# Derive SVM Dual Form Equation

Tags: machine-learning, svm

[image]

For the above Lagrangian function for svm, I can get the partial derivatives as below:
[image]

However, I can't understand how I can plug them to the Lagrangian to derive the dual form? W can be replaced but where does b go?

[image]

Can someone please explain it and give the detailed steps?

Comment: I'm not voting either way, but I'm not convinced this is programming-related enough for you to get a good response here. If you sketched out your steps already and where you've gone wrong, and you read the rules at math.stackexchange, they might be able to give a better response

Comment: I agree: this question would get far better response on math or stats.

Comment: I tried on math but didn't get a response and my question was voted down for reasons I don't know. I could always get help from here in the past so I moved the question here. Indeed I got an answer within no time. Thanks all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your lagrangian is of form

```
L(w, b, a) = 1/2 ||w||^2 + SUM_i a_i (1 - y_i(<w, x_i> + b))
```

and you solve, that in order to achieve extremum, you need to have:

```
w = SUM_i a_i y_i x_i  
SUM_i a_i y_i = 0
```

we plug in first `w`

```
L(w, b, a) = 1/2 <SUM_i a_i y_i x_i, SUM_j a_i y_i x_i> 
               + SUM_i a_i (1 - y_i(<SUM_j a_j y_j x_j , x_i> + b))
           = 1/2 SUM_i,j a_i a_j y_i y_j <x_i, x_j> 
               + SUM_i a_i
               - SUM_i (a_i y_i( SUM_j a_j y_j <x_j, x_i> + b))
           = 1/2 SUM_i,j a_i a_j y_i y_j <x_i, x_j> 
               + SUM_i a_i
               - SUM_i (a_i y_i SUM_j ( a_j y_j <x_j, x_i> ) + a_i y_i b)
           = 1/2 SUM_i,j a_i a_j y_i y_j <x_i, x_j> 
               + SUM_i a_i
               - SUM_i a_i y_i SUM_j ( a_j y_j <x_j, x_i> )
               - SUM_i a_i y_i b
           = 1/2 SUM_i,j a_i a_j y_i y_j <x_i, x_j> 
               + SUM_i a_i
               - SUM_i a_i a_j y_i y_j <x_j, x_i>
               - SUM_i a_i y_i b
           =   + SUM_i a_i
            -1/2 SUM_i a_i a_j y_i y_j <x_j, x_i>
               - b (SUM_i a_i y_i)
```

And now we plug in `SUM_i a_i y_i = 0` which gives us

```
L(w, b, a) = SUM_i a_i - 1/2 SUM_i a_i a_j y_i y_j <x_j, x_i>
```

Consequently **from programmers perspective** you do not care about `b` during optimization process, as you can find optimal `a` without knowing it! Once you have code which does optimization for `a`, you can now recover `b` using original equations etc.

Comment: I super appreciate that you gave an answer to this but (even knowing the derivation) this is awfully hard to read. That inner block is impenetrable, imo, and even something like "<w, x_i>" took me a while to figure out... is that the inner product of w and xi; just a grouped index; vectors; a java-generic-type...? +1 for a good answer, but this reinforces to met that the original question wasn't appropriate for this format

Comment: unfortunately latex support was rejected in meta so. I really like the idea of using "java generic type" in mathematical proofs!